# Ruby on Rails 3 - Create a popup (or something like that) to submit a form

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

---

Hello people

I have a problem here. I don't know much about JS or Jquery, but right now I need to use them.

I have a model (in Ruby on rails 3.0.9) User. The table for users has the following fields

**users**

- id
- first_name
- last_name
- email

When I register a new user, then I'm redirected to the "Show" view, in that view I can choose: go to "index" or go to "edit", if I choose "edit" I'm redirected to the "edit" view, but I don't want to be redirected, I want to be able to load a kind of "popup" instead, with the same functionality of "edit".

Do you have an example of this?
Can you help me, please?

Answer (score 0):

To make things easy, I would just call whatever page you want via a jQuery lightbox. Most lightbox allows you to open another page using a layover, without having to redirect. I have used [Colorbox](http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/) and love it.

Just store some hidden page or div in your `application.html.erb`, then you have a site-wide login page.

Comment: Ok

I have found this [example](https://github.com/ramblex/modal-form)

And works fine, but I need a little more... because everytime you "submit" the dialog-form is closed, then you have to click again in "new article" to add a new one, but what if I want to add more than one before the dialog-form is closed?

I mean, how can I add a button or a link inside the dialog-form, so everytime you "submit" the dialog-form don't get closed, so then you can click the other button (or link), and "reload" the dialog-form to add another "article" until you click "close"

Is that possible??